# Checking a bulk number of proxies in PHP

Tags: php, proxy, fsockopen

I'm working on a proxy scraper, which will search for proxies on the internet, then will check all of them, then store them in a file.
I have around 20k proxies I need to check, but it is too slow the script I have now and it issues a Cloudflare timeout error.
Here's my code right now, but the problem is, it takes aaages and always gives me a timeout error.

```
// this is looped in a foreach
$proxy = "127.0.0.1";
list($host,$port) = explode(':', $proxy);

if($fp = @fsockopen($host,$port,$errCode,$errStr,5)){   
    return $proxy;
}
fclose($fp);
```

I hope someone can provide a solution. Thank you!

Comment: You are honestly better using a coding language that can allow multi threads / background workers to process multiple proxies at once. Proxies are always slow especially free ones, running through a list of 20k good and bad proxies will take a very long time.

Comment: Any way this is possible?